# Using CC1101 module with ESP32S3?

Tags: esp32

I have bought a devboard, a TTGO T-QT Pro based on the esp32-s3.
I'm trying to adapt code for the esp32 (meant for T-Display) to be used with it, but I realised that the SmartRC-CC1101 library doesn't seem to support the esp32-s3 !

Does anyone know how I should proceed with this ?

The code i'm adapting : https://github.com/Jbrimbelibap/io868
Board pinout : [t-qt pro pinout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzXON.jpg)

The pins I tried using with the cc1101 module : [Pin definition in VScode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7uDot.png)